# Display the content of pdf file stored in server in php

Tags: php

I have a PDF file stored in server and the path is stored in database.I wan to display that PDF inside the main page of the site.Here is my code:

```
$check_communication_urban="SELECT * FROM `communication_urban` WHERE `uid`='".$_SESSION['uid']."' AND `cont_id`='".$id."'";<br>
$check_communication_urban_query=mysql_query($check_communication_urban) or die(mysql_error());<br>

$check_communication_urban_arr=mysql_fetch_array($check_communication_urban_query);<br>
$path=$check_communication_urban_arr['path'];<br>

$fullPath="/var/www/esolzdemos.com/public_html".$path;<br>
$file = explode("/",$path);<br>
$filename=$file[4];<br>
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($fullPath));
```

but it gives me gibberish output like following:

%PDF-1.7 3 0 obj <> /Resources 2 0 R /Annots [ 200001 0 R ] /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�í[ÝRÛF¾ç)ÎdÚ�ýZR{EH!%8Ô¹è�Lgm-bI+V��äiú½î£ôªL/2éL¯ÒÜäªg%ÙÈ`C±È�cöG�=:ßù¾³g�NNÀ�Ðá9<}�o¾�At]�på^în`èÄÑ¡�ýýz©¡þIcL��/»ñ9_é1T��¿exs¼�,;ð�}Õct\¢Û`;Äv¡ÀÓÕ_®öµöú;êf�ç\ý´©~k�Ú&éø`ÚÄñ+C�þ�ùÚ°�å�"É%Í ,¢!i �ÅpñyÌ4q.Ë\oòÛ÷.·ÌÒbu�¦����ñ%My °���¬n|�E|=æÇ�u�ØH�7±øyÝbØÄ�òËÌéiÈ ¬+�îjs�ósÊ!³5¬:x�   ®Ó!�s-°bOwïQ£¿÷7a÷�þ�½�í�±#uîGôÍcû »Þ"¦®î³���¤�e,AæáI�Ë"Æ¿±�Ê���J h=l²L�ÏÏË¡�FG»QÂ¤ãúÄ0*�ìyA!«ÙÁÚcýy��õ�I|ßk�¡%ªè8*;¨0ðÓÞ�Ýí·¡ûÃÆÃý�{{ûý�çEÂ�&��Goje�G�ê[��AÙPí4H�Ì1{�«ô`Ý7��Rúí��ÿÜÉï kX�O:vµôàð(�Y�Ázáa )J��jÁ��noëîîdbÉoÊ8�ö�0<ZÏÑ`¤n�äÍ 1ò�£½õÕ´z2$ïc&Ek�±ôÊBùRæ/s©Üi0 \J¯ßUß+È-�üBD/hN5`�òÛ¸¿²Gyw; 8w7{(dºáèß/R�¾f»ur<�¸Þ��J^{)C·3dËpnA�ÓùÄd·�ÆÔÊ�ËDC6;O¼ �þ¦HP5B%RÓØK;6²t�à}�vg²îD¨h©Q�z; �ò}ÌWÊ×]|ùë¾�ïÌZ3Íê¿®9©J�dõ�b�)z©ht*ù�XH£¥�,ZKâmÝ�èÄ>ËD4bñÙ��,bI%4vºÝq� Ãn÷}^8X½3î¼s°�xäLÆøV�äþúËÚ°í{Ä®sD�´A±D±\~·�ê�öØ�K|³ò½A`oð�åb�íÜ ��9ÙDÎòÇNF7÷P�bÆ��fÐ��Ä¦ª1���Léu� �óþlÎ�Î�¡�[c0ÃSÿ�ÁâT¾Ér�,�h�¶ª]÷7�u7'�%ï*~ÃQ�¥"áÜÍ¾RùÈGìZrág(Û�o¨·:Ld:8Ã�BÁé¤,º<�ù:õÒrtâÖL�(Ú2.ë{=Òò,C��Bb·Ïâ"aÈ§o*­ë )Ùë¿ì��åº�Ù/�cL�tÌ16�s°�b%8) gÒË9ý¼À1WÓw�m�ÁòHÀ�fåÆY�æT%d#�yu.�ýÇ��� 4Ã@�$2g\�u �ãfí}Îx�É[[I�éÙD¯³JÌ!S6ÌùH4ÖÙ@<;dß LÉR�Öq)ÔªqÑ<�¬d�Dxk8=>3úß¤À]hÀ�\$4jÍ2×��|J%½�O*Y�ã¢ØÚ±½�9Ùv�Ó�#jùÆd· �¼]ÇÙ)Ý¶V¢2QZ½ºê°¬äËû5_6|Eó7 J²9ÇDÍYSå6uH��:¦ER�ÔK�½ !wéî¢0b ¾ºú8 -�~]�:DÅÂ¸V�FÀüIÏA~aEuècÕüDq)��7­ÚªNäôÿ$��¶ÂÚp-õùÀÚF�¼eà-LI­Å©7IlmTRLàx^j K$«��ÈW�á�`§E.b�óay!2ú6k/Ë5PMm����#)*I"N#V1L�>ä"Ç�s�#0Ã�#ZªdgG<ªú:âY�}­�Y¦E�:ÃíÒô�¼�D;ª÷uGaÓö[¨^¹ÆäÃ¸¦=I_�¸Wþ�©Å­¬Ï~|½ÖYùv�x� endstream endobj 5 0 obj <</Type /Page /Parent 1 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89] /Group << /Type /Group /S /Transparency /CS /DeviceRGB >> /Resources 2 0 R /Annots [ 200002 0 R ] /Contents 6 0 R>> endobj 6 0 obj <</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 2638>> stream x�í[Írã¸¾ÏSà8S¥Áòÿ'7ïÄ»�­d7�òmg+��.��RvÍÓì£���Ë©ò-¹Ì)Ý H�²\kÏ��'±kFA�êF£¿þºÑth�Kâ�ï�CÎÉO?Ã[ÿ¿%.u�,_}}F¾úÆ%®CC��-ÈéÙ+çs¾´rº¡îjÇ¼�]>Ù5¿-ài/¾ª%��Ã ����á�ÅÔ   HÒ &g9ùéõß÷÷ægröÞìÇJ?V5=�¦�G£�x ÓVÑ_ÇäaÇäT×�d²ª«%YHAxÁæR±\^�»ó±WÅi'ýk�Ü¯�ï�Ô��ª]^^ÒNDÅV"�pXÒ¹ê¥ë¾ãÓ4�¥4ôÉ[�!Q�,�Bø��Å h2²ËÞ�'«ÍRT~5çÄä¢{Ü5áïºæig'ô©��4õÛÙ   ¨KÛ5ø®[�ßqí­ÅR*³�³�áDé�¦5L\Ýà%dÅUÉ*�qµÙ~�Õ7ä¢áD¦uZ}Â¨·öi¹R7º¥$5¯~aDÃj%¢ªùR±¢Ý@j¶� z!ß¿fïß¼­ß¿!iêf£Äp�ÁÁÇáy_6Gtï�¹cÄÏ;u/¶=ÝO<ÿScÝ=âzv»¦��ÆÖGBJþ(ôJjqý®É·\1¡¶þ�m8¥g<½Á£8¢�Ó@q×ÀÞ=2=¥(±Ocw$Ê�ó¦�ú��óÄlÎMhä�ä!ïXÎHSbPÐä¯LÕàñ`-ø�gäS%2�ü*+-Ö�¸P¥7k^ðEfÈã8þd&�BêE­Íx£�T<«ÅZjRÛ¹F±«�©%|�ëL´ãY�±�2©F8-õÝûäBqaîs¨Á[êµ�É¹Kf�j¥øZh�¤âÃ�øõLPã¡¼�ÆA�PÞQj Ê÷M!r�ó#AH��"'¤²2Ùìú�]ù¢aPSEÞ�FÃ8�¸o×±¯Cï/!ÔÏ�Î�óhæ�ÊÊ.äÎl·ôÄZoP'NÀÖ0áä¤�à�/e&\8CEç�½]ÜÌ�u3:\7ÂLê´¥2#xJãt2��L9xEµfÆ8 Ê Ó¹�O�=´É_¢f%�¤ä¨¼��sÄVPÎãe�h£�ÞÛÉ¡�ô0�ÀÏûÁTj�)®�V­~eå#m ÷è×�æç�lÕÇµ ét�EÕÚtf¦¤¿� H�Ù�Lå&�ÅÈ0q©�´:�7JèÜ,H÷W¼Æ�7ÃD¯ �ÿª`Åuya!^ Zñ+¸RãJ¬Aö�«­�'Y0ù��èT�ò���aì`iª�þ¥Û0H!aÝ'<)7W¢´�^¾PU­¹uÅ ÌÂKD�.¢NèÀ�G�°�¨þñ"êX�¿ñêSõðEõÔ¨d:��ü@@�6þÁ �ðÊ   ÎÂUv�   s`iï�mÓ�üJ,�Ú© ùq8��}��n«GÖ�+%LÊ1"�1�J@Ø�<ÿ�È¤Ji`ÐJ�êÑ�+h±¬B·ÚÇ<¶¸®ìJAÃ`mi¨¸­jÐ¢LÁÕ?:°Þc4�â-KúHÖBv�i¤��Ng%'¡�¿I·�ã¾ÙWÜ�#]h ÑÊj�Y2 wÄ�mv(+iL�´£<9_qx    Ú $�¡b9R��ÒD9'�PYSéÚ¨�RLáe ¸�QÍJ·_BÎ³Jâ`!~_f îñ Ç¡Àõ���4µ¬d)�U�ãD�$Àû e#?ü6�rU�ê,Vä5dEÜ¦��@6×�ÌÆaBS�îsÄ¼Ì©dçàíU�ÚÝVYSà~¨·dµ�¨¦�¹ZÝÖ¡°èf¾jð 1&àp�Ä4²ÉN�½�Í5«À&ý¤Û�K�µ�Õ(HÙÎÀêà�¸\g²íúêSx4®�z#QÞq­[.úÈâæãVÑÔI�¸µ­�AYvÈ2ÁÇ�Æ²§ª^mÑî`Nî¤°�ìÌv%s¤&àãÏBÿ ë�UzÁ�aô½­ÏîÍàF`+u³Ëÿ}`d±Ee~�3«�)V@¼rK�-¦¾Ô�È¬üØÜÕTtÌòøP�µ:6F¥>MÆó�ý]B¥øZ.qï®/Cn�Î�ÿ §¼fÀ]ºÍ!·¸ü0¥�MQÞ*o3yM~aë°¨(¤jS¬¶e8Ó6Ç-Y}�´�]�v&�Ê_ÜþËt{ß£N_Ã��êöQN X�ìú9P�$Â�¸¡p{Ý^KÛ¡Þ�é�Që|ìK��RW�»2¹`ä%>ðªØVñL.HX.Ì�×��eÛÒrÓ×õØöÅ£?C÷`²ôÙ�8z�G'Çóèt$Ê�Tûä�BçÙ�ÛÙ}×ÅÎë¡Ü;Ý�7d!Ti�z'BòòPîì%uí&#�ÎqNØ¹4ýAÜÂlãÑÌæNXjàdÎÍ^©0�û�)¦G7ð{�%Ó�%«$Ø)b·�ÐMDa2YÉÃ|E¥G¢�&ÉH�Ó+�5È,N±åìCò���Ù"�� )wûÏØnÿÙÌàìysû¡­t¶�6ÀÐË�\H}0�Vä[ ¼¯[nfº¤Â�ÞÍ=ïçÞÔ5Jc¿@Înú=°UB�µéRA5ê" ¢É:n<�ñè�ú~Åvó/ E2Å��0�D¤ÄmÂ¹bZÀ�b³vo�ÄmwÁ6+®Úþ£�áÖ¨fµÐ¤¸3��ÒÈ,[ÀXl5í7�¿wñ�·Ï*�C@   úT~þ8��Ò0Éòg¾º­�à>��#!n�%Ì¡l;ìÎtb+�×p¥A��Ùk�6vû¨Øju¸&,7v©ëvm.«OsÜ¶#ßpìä«±KÄûÚàÐ��.lÑÁ��õEëÂY¾�µ©]´û/à/eSÙÃ£x²ç»ø(ÂPDr&�a!h�ÄX=Ú��^fìñÍ�n�±¥Øq¯N8Yzîe �¾;J!M�§¡ )Þ þ¶Ñ@ºÝ²�Fm±4�Û�È- [k��+À~-O/�4�ýÉZ¯]�Òñ�9W ¥¨ÚçW¶�àvµú7�NcC�Ù4�ÛóH×æÙCÖî�YÃaqj;»ÝUa0Y�#>��:­^Û&�®�Àü�é¡¬|Á�ì¡QÖ�"»�þ�ya�ò`%×Ì¶0WÄç@aiÂ � ;ºÆ�ìaS��»nÓh�&4�ú:B�[�²��,luïAÈØ¯@¶ó&ÇÚvT�î3Å   AceæÉ×B|°u[ÜñÐ î1Ì¶küP�2�©çu^Ãl�o@��Vþá%4þ�S¯^]ì;ýã¬¸çk¯þôn|z endstream endobj 7 0 obj <> /Resources 2 0 R /Annots [ 200003 0 R ] /Contents 8 0 R>> endobj 8 0 obj <> stream x�í[ÍrÛ6¾û)ö(Ï(@�¹)9qZÿÄ¦�(Ó�EH¥G$d�´ò8y�>JN��{ë©��åV�eW?´EÍH$°f¿Å·�`Sâx0>�køô~ß#�Rèï½ áõ!F�C!ìA;Ü£OétWE§UÓÖtüG+kó°�70i<ÿ«û��ãz\�´CSÃ\�PÜ!Ü�0�O�_÷Ùÿá3ØÇ%µ¿5ØRn7�'�ýzÿË�¡�åº*ÍµÈôTr ®���À¿í±âRÈ<öøÿ�Ì¦±Ýyh£Ñ�LUÔbG �   ¹Ò3í¦}l88cqlxE  w@Kè­Bùe§�qâß�����á·~� °!�`?�t�kãüÿ60kcÄvlbyà9�¸tbÁ3¡¨NCtö;�¬³ÇE^�4�ãÒ��Ö{êZT�6&Z¯ûXîl.Ïe��8C]ãÛ§-6@P'Èäµ u|~�ë,7�é �,��¦áÖØç4úåu�/è¥ ºR£�¬�Í¦Îk:¤ÂxïþbïÛÛbÂ÷�½�K3ðÆhËñËÔcKb¢Â8f   d�ìÉØh��R÷ïè�¨-µ Ó� a6©1�I�þ�õ�Ð/j­,ß<  ,��ú�yÄ+ÃsÆ ö¢YZN¿ÚS·�IÙn@héÍÇ�áeë$lwÕ>[Y�E�À�=Û¶E\þ¤�æ�®�+~MgMîZm� ¼h¸8½<>úùÞ·~:o½==©0/*"ÚºS[�~yî�Sÿ~~tÚi´L"¼Ë�mqNl�=ÛÂm³GWåÙÛ¤93�37C%�°}¶�/OÞ·.ªÌïZT�jÑËÛ3Ç3�6E�ÀW�J³-N|û²¯�ÕÕ¦æ(m^WkÃ³P){�¤ä6aÓ�@±��À5SmNßÊSmå¶­Ê�@�Oür+|þ®²3R²gNÙÊ³gµ�­Ä�:�^��V>ôÌ©[yò¬Ú´K�è?E{{7�Äõÿ)³n{*'a� endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /OCG /Name (print) /Usage << /Print <> /View <> >> >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Type /OCG /Name (view) /Usage << /Print <> /View <> >> >> endobj 11 0 obj <> endobj 12 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 11 0 R /F2 12 0 R >> /XObject << >> /Properties <> /ExtGState << >> >> endobj 13 0 obj <> endobj 14 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /First 13 0 R /Last 13 0 R >> endobj 200001 0 obj <> /H /I>> endobj 200002 0 obj <> /H /I>> endobj 200003 0 obj <> /H /I>> endobj 15 0 obj << /Creator (HTML2PDF - TCPDF) /Producer (TCPDF 5.0.002 (http://www.tcpdf.org) (TCPDF)) /CreationDate (D:20140611040032+00'00') /ModDate (D:20140611040032+00'00') >> endobj 16 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R /OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null] /PageLayout /SinglePage /PageMode /UseNone /Names << >> /Outlines 14 0 R /PageMode /UseOutlines /ViewerPreferences << /Direction /L2R >> /OCProperties <> <>]>>>> >> endobj xref 0 17 0000000000 65535 f 0000006251 00000 n 0000006766 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000198 00000 n 0000001978 00000 n 0000002167 00000 n 0000004876 00000 n 0000005065 00000 n 0000006323 00000 n 0000006435 00000 n 0000006547 00000 n 0000006654 00000 n 0000006938 00000 n 0000007038 00000 n 0000007817 00000 n 0000008003 00000 n 200001 3 0000007103 00000 n 0000007341 00000 n 0000007579 00000 n trailer << /Size 17 /Root 16 0 R /Info 15 0 R >> startxref 8413 %%EOF

can you please tell me the proper coed to display the content of the pdf?

Comment: You will not be able to embed the PDF into your page without using a third party tool of some kind (as far as I know, HTML 5 might have solved this).  But, just to get the data from your PHP script to be identified as a PDF file you can set header("application/pdf") (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312230/proper-mime-media-type-for-pdf-files)

Comment: I just add the header but it give me the same gibberish output.

Comment: That "gibberish output" is the content of the PDF file. What did you expect to get?

Comment: see similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679756/show-a-pdf-files-in-users-browser-via-php-perl