# PHP Mysql view PDF file error

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, mysqli

I was trying to view a PDF from my a MySQL database but it gets stuck on loading.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","username","password");

    //check if errors occur in connection to database
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        //return the error
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $filename = $row['name'];
    $query = "SELECT content from images WHERE id = 7"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($query,$con)or die(mysqli_error()); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);  

    echo $row['content'];
?>
```

Comment: May I ask what exactly do you mean by writing `gets stuck on loading`?

Comment: The code is working but it doesnt open the pdf content, it stucks on pdf loading where you can see it on the lower left of the page

Comment: And the value in $row['content'] is legit for PDF? (Maybe when you inserted it you accidentally encoded something?)

Comment: yes it is legit. i dont know why it stucked.

Comment: Try to alter your headers according to the final edit of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679756/show-a-pdf-files-in-users-browser-via-php-perl

Comment: still not working. it keep stucking

Comment: Is this behavior repeat for all the pdf files in your DB?

Comment: yes but i try it first for 1 pdf file only to test but unfortunately, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use dompdf or TCP pdf library for better and extended functionality.

or try to use ob_clean() method in starting of the line.

or remove first header("Content-type: application/pdf"); and check whether query is working or not.

Comment: where to put ob_clean() method?

Comment: none of these methods works. btw thanks for answering

Comment: can you show me the url, so i can see what's happening with client side(browser)?

Comment: I am pretty sure if you use DOM PDF library your problem will resolve.

Comment: how to use the DOM PDF library? can you provide example or tutorial?

Comment: <code> ob_clean ();
 $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf->load_html("$cm_100_html");  // 
 $paper_size = array(50,0,700,885);
 $dompdf->set_paper($paper_size);
 $dompdf->render();
 $output = $dompdf->output();
 $idss="CM-100_".$internal_number;
 $uploads=wp_upload_dir();
 $uploaddir=$uploads['basedir']."/pdf_store/";
 $file_to_save = "$uploaddir".$idss.'.pdf';
 file_put_contents($file_to_save, $output);                                                                                                    </code>

Comment: $cm_100_html  is the html container.  In your example do this $cm_100_html.=$row['content'];

Comment: still if you have problem let me know any help( braut@avika.in)

Comment: can you inject the dompdf to my example code? so i can try it now. Im confused

Comment: <?php
require_once("lib/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 
?>  Add this in your script

Comment: `ob_clean (); $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); $dompdf->load_html($row['content'];);  $paper_size = array(50,0,700,885); $dompdf->set_paper($paper_size); $dompdf->render(); $output = $dompdf->output();`

Comment: Just test it and let me know whether it works or not